# "Hinglish" Kids movie about a band of misfits on an adventure who take the help of an imperial ghost to defeat some thugs

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

I recall as a child watching this movie many years ago in my hometown in India, on cable television. I want to re-watch it but I just can't remember the name. "Hinglish" refers to a blend of the languages Hindi (which is commonly spoken in India) and English.

**Film Genre**: Adventure

**Characters**: An Indian cast with the protagonists of the movie as a band of maybe five or six children, led by a boy named Rahul, who wore a red checkered shirt throughout the movie if I remember correctly. The antagonists were a group of thugs constantly trying to foil the protagonists.

**Language**: The movie's language was primarily English I believe, with the protagonists speaking mostly English, while the thugs spoke some Hindi.

**Plot**: It was an Indiana Jones-esque plot with the misfits trying to procure some artefact, and along the way they meet a ghost who died during the imperial times, who stays with them throughout the journey, guiding and helping them along the way.

**Specific Scene**: The movie's climax occurs at the end, in a massive showdown between the misfits and the thieves, with a group of 40 or 50 thieves who kidnap the children, but the ghost singlehandedly defeats all the thieves, frees the children and performs a miracle by helping one of them, whose leg is disabled walk again.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: Maybe 2012 or 2013. I'd only seen it once, and suddenly remembered it recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this ***[Bhoot and Friends](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1807978/)*** (2010)...?

[image: Promotional image for "Bhoot and Friends" showing the main characters (2010).]

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhoot_and_Friends), the plot involves four kids who meet a friendly ghost that helps them to find a precious treasure.

> The film revolves around four kids who are currently on their summer holidays at their maternal grandmother's home and they meet a friendly ghost with magical powers to help them in finding a precious treasure called "Neelmani Ka Khazana" (transl. Blue sapphire's treasure).

The film features a mixture of English language and Hindi.

The kids are shown exploring what looks like an ancient temple at one point.

The ghost in the film is dressed like an Imperial Indian soldier and the kids refer to him as 'Ghost Uncle.'

Ghost Uncle helps the kids fight off a bunch of thugs in the climactic battle of the film.

The central kid in the movie poster above is a boy named Raghav who wears a checkered shirt.

The boy to the right of him is named Ali and has a brace on his left leg. Ghost Uncle uses magic to heal Ali's leg near the very end of the film.

You can view the scene in question at around the 1:44:38 mark in the video below.

Comment: Yes, this was definitely the movie. Thank you!